# Change color of Box on Crystal Report using c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am looking to change the color of a box object on my Crystal Report depending upon the Label Color parameter that is passed through with the parent object.

```
public class PartType
    {
        public string partTypeID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int label_R { get; set; }
        public int label_G { get; set; }
        public int label_B { get; set; }
        public int text_R { get; set; }
        public int text_G { get; set; }
        public int text_B { get; set; }

        public Color GetLabelColor()
        {
            Color color = new Color();
            color = Color.FromArgb(label_R, label_G, label_B);
            return color;
        }

        public Color GetTextColor()
        {
            Color color = new Color();
            color = Color.FromArgb(text_R, text_G, text_B);
            return color;
        }
    }
```

I am unsure how to access the fill color of the box object as the code below is as far as I understand how to actually access the box through my initial C# code.

```
rptMRPLabel.Section3.ReportObjects["boxTitle"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after alot of messing around;

```
BoxObject i = rptMRPLabel.Section3.ReportObjects["boxTitle"] as BoxObject;
                i.FillColor = color;
```

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer.